# Where is the fold expression ()?

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Reference [fluentCPP article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/03/19/what-c-fold-expressions-can-bring-to-your-code/)

The below code explanation says that this structure inherits from several lambdas, can be constructed from those lambdas, and folds over the `using` expression.

```
template<typename... Lambdas>
struct overloaded : public Lambdas...
{
    explicit overloaded(Lambdas... lambdas) : Lambdas(lambdas)... {}

    using Lambdas::operator()...;
};
```

My doubt is that parentheses i.e () indicate a c++17 fold expression but I don't see any enclosing parentheses around the using statement. How will it fold?

Comment: The article is wrong, there are no fold expressions here, just good ol' pack expansions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a fold expression. You cannot have any expression statements in class scope. And as you point out, there are no parentheses that are part of the fold expression syntax.

This is a declaration with a parameter pack expansion. Pack expansions can be used in many more context than just fold expressions.

> what will this statement do?

It will declare

```
using L::operator();
```

for each type `L` in the parameter pack `Lambdas`.

> Usually using is used same as typedef

That's not the only use case of that keyword. In this context, it is used to introduce a member (function) of a base class into the derived class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Corrected. Parameter pack expansion in general was in C++11, but apparently using them in using declarations was introduced in C++17.

Comment: can you please detail your response in context of my question?

Comment: @Test The answer to your question `How will it fold?` is that it doesn't fold because it isn't a fold. The answer to your question `Where is the fold expression ()?` is that there isn't a fold expression in the example.

Comment: what will this statement do? using Lambdas::operator()...;  Usually using is used same as typedef but here it's usage isn't clear to me.